# Unable to start activity implementing LocationListener for detecting location of android device using GPS

Tags: android, gps

I develop simple application that detects the location of android device and display its values in text Views

The application crashes once it starts throwing RuntimeException.

Following is GPS.java

```
public class GPS extends Activity implements LocationListener {
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private LocationManager locationManager;
    private String provider;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.gps);
        latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

        LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);
        boolean enabled = service
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        if (!enabled) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(
                    android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivity(intent);
        }

      Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
     provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,false);
    Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

        if (location != null) {
            Log.d("PROVIDER", "Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");

            onLocationChanged(location);
        } else {
            latituteField.setText("Location not available");
            longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
        }
    }
```

Log is as following :

> 10-09 16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>   10-09 16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):
>   java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity
>   ComponentInfo{com.example.gps/com.example.gps.GPS}:
>   java.lang.NullPointerException 10-09 16:49:35.733:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1616):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1956)
>   10-09 16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1981)
>   10-09 16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:123) 10-09
>   16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at
>   android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1147)
>   10-09 16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):   at
>   android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99) 10-09
>   16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at
>   android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137) 10-09 16:49:35.733:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1616):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424) 10-09
>   16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 10-09
>   16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at
>   java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511) 10-09 16:49:35.733:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1616):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
>   10-09 16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):   at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551) 10-09
>   16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at
>   dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 10-09 16:49:35.733:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1616): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
>   10-09 16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):   at
>   com.example.gps.GPS.onCreate(GPS.java:44) 10-09 16:49:35.733:
>   E/AndroidRuntime(1616):   at
>   android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:4465) 10-09
>   16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):     at
>   android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1049)
>   10-09 16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):   at
>   android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:1920)
>   10-09 16:49:35.733: E/AndroidRuntime(1616):   ... 11 more

Comment: Can you attach crash log here?

Comment: Check for all permissions in manifest file and please attach the log.

Comment: You have call MainActivity class but u want to call gps class. replace MainActivity with GPS in AndroidMenifestfile

Comment: I edit the post sorry for bad formatting but I don't know how to post it in well format

Comment: yea , I know that this line makes the app crash but I don't know why

Comment: my below answer may help you.

Comment: You have not initialize locationManager. Currently it is null. You can initialize it using below code locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
Add this line after setContentView()

Answer (score 0):

It looks like problem is while showing location setting screen.

Use below code for enabling/disabling GPS

public void turnGPSOn()
{

```
 Intent intent = new Intent("android.location.GPS_ENABLED_CHANGE");
 intent.putExtra("enabled", true);
 this.ctx.sendBroadcast(intent);

String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
if(!provider.contains("gps"))
    { 
    //if gps is disabled
    final Intent poke = new Intent();
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider"); 
    poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
    this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
}
```

}

public void turnGPSOff()
{

```
String provider = Settings.Secure.getString(ctx.getContentResolver(), Settings.Secure.LOCATION_PROVIDERS_ALLOWED);
if(provider.contains("gps")){ //if gps is enabled
    final Intent poke = new Intent();
    poke.setClassName("com.android.settings", "com.android.settings.widget.SettingsAppWidgetProvider");
    poke.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_ALTERNATIVE);
    poke.setData(Uri.parse("3")); 
    this.ctx.sendBroadcast(poke);
}
```

}

Comment: Sorry but the problem isn't in this part the problem in this line   provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,false);  
it throws null pointer exception

Comment: Your locationManager is null. You have not initialized it.
You can initialize it by using below code

locationManager = (LocationManager)getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

Answer (score 0):

I guess you might have found your solution. But I posted this answer for people who might have same type of issue in future.You have only declared `locationManager` but have not yet initialised it. But you have later declared new `LocationManager` called `service`. So you can either use the service as `LocationManager` for your activity or either initialise `locationManager` like this.

```
public class GPS extends Activity implements LocationListener {
private TextView latituteField;
private TextView longitudeField;
private LocationManager locationManager;
private String provider;


@Override 
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.gps);
    latituteField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
    longitudeField = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.TextView04);

    locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);//now you have initialised locationManager, and is available for use.
    LocationManager service = (LocationManager) getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);//Declared and initialised new LocationManager service but only accessible inside onCreate method. 
    boolean enabled = locationManager
            .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

    if (!enabled) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(
                android.provider.Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
        startActivity(intent);
    } 

  Criteria criteria = new Criteria();
 provider = locationManager.getBestProvider(criteria,false);
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(provider);

    if (location != null) { 
        Log.d("PROVIDER", "Provider " + provider + " has been selected.");

        onLocationChanged(location); 
    } else { 
        latituteField.setText("Location not available");
        longitudeField.setText("Location not available");
    } 
} `
```

Now there wont be any null Pointer exception.